# Xamarin Forms Event Bubbling and Invoking Operations on a Custom Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, icommand, eventhandler, xamarin.forms

I am creating a custom Xamarin Forms control that contains three buttons (1,2,3) inside a view. Let's just call it a `GaugeView` for the sake of this example. Here is how it is currently setup:

- The `GuageView` has a custom renderer on both iOS and Android called `GuageViewRenderer`.
- The `GuageView` exposes event handlers for `Clicked1`, `Clicked2`, and `Clicked3`.
- The `GuageView` exposes `ICommand` properties for `Click1`, `Click2`, and `Click3`.

The problem is, I need to fire the event handlers from the custom renderer because only the native platform control knows when one of the buttons has been pressed. How do you bubble the events back up to the `GuageView`, which is where the shared code lives?

I was planning to wire up the commands and the event handlers down inside the custom renderer, but I'm having a heck of a time with it since events can only be fired from within the original class (`GuageView`).

Is there a better way to structure this? The main thing I am trying to do is expose the platform native guage and wire its buttons up so the event handlers in the shared code (`GuageView`) gets the event firings.

Comment: Just to note I have already looked through Xamarin tutorials on custom renderers but there doesn't seem to be anything on how the shared code gets access to events that happen native which is the root of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you can't raise events outside of the class that declares them.  So you'll have to add a method to `GaugeView` that will raise the events.  I would also have that same method invoke the commands as well.  So in `GaugeView`

```
public void RaiseClick1() {
    var clicked1 = Clicked1;
    if (clicked1 != null)
        clicked1(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    if (Command1 != null && Command1.CanExecute(Command1Paramter))
         Command1.Execute(Command1Parameter);
}
```

Then in `GaugeViewRender` whenever you need to notify the view that a button was clicked:

```
Element.RaiseClick1();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was kind of thinking about exposing the event firing method as public but it just felt wrong. Thanks for confirming my concern. :-)

Comment: My ICommand properties live on the GuageView but the actual execution of the command should be tied to the native button click in the renderer so they are tied to the native platform control, wouldn't I want to raise Clicked events when the command is executed?

Comment: `RaiseClicked` both raises the click event and executes the command.  Having the command code in the same places means you don't have to repeat it in each native renderer.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but maybe for the future: You can raise the click event of a button from outside using the IButtonController interface.

The Xamarin.Forms.Button class implements this interface which provides one single method: SendClicked

By casting your Xamarin.Forms element in the renderer (this.Element) to IButtonController you're able to call this method and raise the clicked event of the Xamarin.Forms.Button.

I also created a blog post about this topic: http://software.fauland.cc/?p=5637

Comment: Why the downgrade?